# Initiating AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having an issue getting started with AngularJS. I have downloaded the minified file and have it living in a JS directory along with a app.js file. Everything works until I try calling the app.js file. Then it breaks. Here's my code.

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>    
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <h1>Intro to Data Binding</h1>
    <div ng-controller="DBController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="userName" />
        <p>Hello, {{userName}}.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
function DBController($scope) {
    $scope.userName;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What's the error output in your developer console of the browser?

Comment: Is this the complete app.js?

Comment: He's not even replying tho

Comment: There are at least a dozen questions almost identical to this on the site; most likely, you are trying to use a new version of Angular, but the way your controller is declared is an antiquated, depreciated technique that won't work in angular 1.3 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

on your `body` tag do `ng-app="app"`

then, in your .js file...

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller("DBController", function($scope){
    $scope.userName = "My Name";
})
```

It also might be helpful to get a basic understanding of angular

the angular team provides a lot of useful videos and other resources
https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started

Free Video Tutorials: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Comment: This is about the exact answer I posted earlier

Comment: yep, looks like you posted while i was writing mine. oh well

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean to give off attitude. all i meant was i didnt copy your answer, that you posted while i writing mine, also i felt like leaving my answer was appropriate since they were not exactly the same, i provided explaination and additional references to tutorials and such.